# Why can't I access google.com when tethering?

Tags: tethering, dns

I am paying my wireless carrier (MetroPCS) for the "hotspot" feature, which is required in order for me to tether. However, strange things are a happening....

I can't access google.com, although I can access it via IP address - 208.54.90.53. Which leads me to believe it has something to do with DNS resolution.

HOWEVER

I can access android.stackexchange.com directly.

BUT

I can't access facebook.com either directly or via IP.

... I've tested this on multiple laptops, and the issue is the same. What in the world is going on?

Comment: Can you access these sites from your phone?

Comment: Yep I can access them fine

Comment: Then most likely your laptop isn't receiving the DNS settings from the phone, or isn't using them. You need to check the network configuration on the laptop, and check it's using DHCP and not a static IP address.

Comment: On my laptop (Windows 7) I checked Local Area Connection > Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 > Properties > Advanced and I see that under "IP Addresses" It says "DHCP Enabled". Do I need to check something/somewhere else?

Comment: What DNS are you using? Have you tried using Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)?

Comment: I had it set to "obtain DNS server address automatically", but the issue still occurs when I try setting it to Google's public DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Once I disconnected my other LAN and Wifi connection that were connected but had no internet, it worked. Before I had no FB or Google as you say. Must have been a conflict

Answer (score -1):

I think that gives me a feel that your ISP provider may have blocked some sites. Why don't you try contacting your ISP vendor ask for a resolution they have firewalls installed over their backend which I guess may be the reason you can't access the Google.com or Facebook. Okay try installing some free proxy softwares and then try accessing the Google.com or Facebook.com if by that time it start working fine then I guess I was correct it's the problem with the ISP end not your end.

Comment: I'm not being blocked as I can access those sites just fine from my phone. The problem only occurs when I tether and appears to be DNS related.